# 3.3v to GPIO input using relay

Tags: gpio, relay, voltage

I'm exploring various ways to detect higher voltage using the Pi and have come up with a circuit where the 5v would energize the coil of a relay which would switch 3.3v from the Pi's internal 3.3v supply pin to a GPIO pin.

The 5v will be from a standard wall adapter rated for 1amp and will only be on for brief periods 20-30m weekly.

Is this a viable circuit?

I'm mainly concerned about the load on the GPIO pin - do I need a resistor to limit the current from the 3.3v supply?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNqjsU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just connect Pi ground to one relay contact and a GPIO set as an input to the other.  Then set the internal pull-up GPIO resistor.  The GPIO would then read high when the relay is open and low when the relay is closed.

You need no other circuit components.

Comment: On the Pi side, the simple connection should be just fine... However, there needs to be a protection diode in parallel with the relay coil on the input side.

Comment: @RubberStamp Is there anything to protect on the relay coil side?  It's switched by the wall wart which I didn't think would be affected by back EMF from the coil.

Comment: Without looking at the schematic of the power supply, there's no way to know if the diode is needed or not.  If it's unknown, the diode should be included.

Comment: I was definitely overthinking this problem. Thank you for the simple and elegant solution. One thing I found was that the internal pull-up was being a bit unreliable so I used an external one.

Answer (score 0):

I have about the same question. I have a 220V relay to be connected to a raspberry pi input via the contacts. One of the contacts is already connected to a 5V supply. Do I need a resistor to connect to a GPIO input?

Thanks

FCoo

Comment: The answer section is for answers. This should be a question unto itself.